# AWS S3 Post Policy - what is the correct way to use the x-amz-checksum-sha256 condition?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, http-headers, aws-sdk, sha256

I'm using S3 presigned post policies to upload files to an S3 bucket and I'm trying to make use of the `x-amz-checksum-sha256` condition, but I can not figure out how to successfully post a file using `x-amz-checksum-sha256`. Whenever I try to post a file AWS returns a 400 with the message of `Value for x-amz-checksum-sha256 header is invalid` but I don't know what this means. In what way is the sha256 value I'm producing "invalid"?

Here's an example of how I'm trying to accomplish this. I'm using a standard file `<input>` element for file selection.

```
const fileBlob = new Blob([file]);
const arrayBuffer = await fileBlob.arrayBuffer();
const fileUint8 = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", fileUint8);
const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
const sha256Checksum = hashArray
  .map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
  .join('');
const base64Checksum = btoa(sha256Checksum);

const postData = await backendAPICallToGetPresignedPost({base64Checksum});

const postForm = new FormData();
Object.keys(postData.fields).forEach((key) => {
  return postForm.append(key, postData.fields[key]);
});
postForm.append('x-amz-checksum-algorithm', 'SHA256');
postForm.append('x-amz-checksum-sha256', base64Checksum);
postForm.append('file', file);

axios.post('S3-url', postForm,
  headers: {
    'x-amz-checksum-algorithm': 'SHA256',
    'x-amz-checksum-sha256': base64Checksum,
  },
);
```

And here is how I am created the presigned post policy. The base64 encoded checksum is passed to the server to use when creating the policy.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new aws.S3({
    region: awsRegion,
    accessKeyId: s3AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: s3SecretAccessKey,
});

return await s3.createPresignedPost({
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Fields: {
        key: `${s3ProductImageFolder}/${brandName}/${fileName}`,
    },
    Conditions: [
        { 'x-amz-checksum-algorithm': 'SHA256' },
        { 'x-amz-checksum-sha256': base64Checksum },
    ],
});
```

I've confirmed that the sha256 value that I am generating with the above javascript is the same as what is generated by the sha256sum GNU utility and by [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef). The test file that I am using generates the following sha256 hash: 1789f8b9f648498f5abcfe3c71b7fb4047143b431022d477d27a7acba64d2ca8 (in base64: MTc4OWY4YjlmNjQ4NDk4ZjVhYmNmZTNjNzFiN2ZiNDA0NzE0M2I0MzEwMjJkNDc3ZDI3YTdhY2JhNjRkMmNhOA==)

Comment: x-amz-checksum-sha256 is digest base64 encoded, not digest hex encoded then base64 encoded.  It should be the output of `btoa(hashArray)`, or `F4n4ufZISY9avP48cbf7QEcUO0MQItR30np6y6ZNLKg=`

Comment: @AnonCoward Thanks for pointing out my mistake, but I'm still unable to get it to work. I've tried base64 encoding both the `hashArray` and `hashBuffer` and I'm still receiving the same message from AWS. I also tried encoding the `Uint8Array` version of the `hashBuffer`. I'm not too familiar with hashing and encoding in client side JS so there is probably something obvious that I'm missing.